# Accessing a model from another unrelated model takes a very long time

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0

I have a query in a CakePHP 3.0 table with a `formatResults()` method applied to it.

In order to carry out this calculation, data is required from a table in a *different* database (Currencies).

I am currently using this code to gather the data and pass it to the function:

```
$currencies = TableRegistry::get('Currencies');

$currencyValues = $currencies
  ->findByCurrno($options['currency'])
  ->cache('currency'.$options['currency']);

$currencyValues = $currencyValues->first()->toArray()  

$query->formatResults(function ($results) use ($currencyValues) {
  return $results->map(function($row) use ($currencyValues) {
    $row['converted_earnings'] = $row['earned'] / $currencyValues['cur'.$row['currency']];
    $row['converted_advances'] = $row['advances'] / $currencyValues['cur'.$row['currency']];
    return $row;
  });
});
```

The problem is, this code seems to take a very long time to execute, even though it is only iterating through a few hundred rows of data.

Further investigation revealed that if I do not collect the data from the 'currencies' table and instead declare `$currencyValues` as an array with fixed numbers the code takes a full second less to execute.

Through commenting out parts of the code, I have isolated this to be the cause of the problem:

```
$currencyValues = $currencies
 ->findByCurrno($options['currency'])
 ->cache('currency'.$options['currency']);
```

If I remove this part of the code then everything runs quickly, and as soon as I add it in (even if I do not use the data it returns and use the static array) the page takes far longer to load. It should be noted that this problem occurs whether or not I use the `->cache()` method, and that the query itself reports that it takes 0-1ms in the sql dump.

My question is - why is this slowing down my execution so much and how can I stop it? It is pretty much a requirement that I use the data from this table for the operation, so I am looking for a way to speed it up.

Comment: Sounds pretty fishy. I'd suggest to use a tool like [**Xdebug**](http://www.xdebug.org/docs/profiler) to properly profile the code in order to figure where exactly the time is spent, and then go from there.

Comment: And for a short in the dark, do you have [**`cacheMetadata`**](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/database-basics.html#configuration) enabled? And does the code show the same behavior when disabling the debug mode?

Comment: @ndm Hi, thanks for the response - `cacheMetadata` is enabled as it is recommended to do so by default. I have installed Xdebug but I am getting a lot of information, not really sure what I should be looking for! Disabling debug doesn't seem to change much.  The problem does seem to be with my secondary database, which is a local mysql database. If I make multiple queries from it the total time doesn't really increase, so it's the act of connecting in the first place that seems to be causing the problem.

Comment: You can post the generated profile here if you need help with interpreting it. As for the connecting thing, are you using `localhost` in the database connection configuration? If so, try using `127.0.0.1` instead, I remember similar problems that could be solved this way.

Comment: Well, I feel pretty silly! That seems to be what caused the problem. I could have sworn it started out as `127.0.0.1` and I changed it to `localhost` to test it, but I changed it to `127.0.0.1` and it's working fine now. Thanks! Feel free to post an answer and I'll accept it.